# Condition in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is there a way to write a condition in .htaccess (mod_rewrite) to apply the redirect rule **IF the referrer contain ".google." while at the same time "image" is not found in the accept header**.

So far I have rule that applies to all requests (except my domain) to images redirect to my web page that contains that image. So instead of displaying image in blank page, now it redirects to the post.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^manufacturers/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/.]+\.jpe?g$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^manufacturers/([^/]+/[^/]+)/[^/.]+\.jpe?g$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Now I want to allow every request except IF the referrer contain ".google." while at the same time "image" is not found in the accept header.

If you can answer, at least please share some resources so I can solve it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.google\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !image
RewriteRule ^manufacturers/([^/]+/[^/]+)/[^/.]+\.jpe?g$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What if (vice versa) I wanted the rule should be applied if  "image" contained in the accept header.  **RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image** is correct?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.google\.` checks for "**.google.**" as you provided. But what if I want to check "**\.google\.**" ? Then is it `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \\.google\\.` ?